# Is it ok to drive with the tire scraped like this?

Tags: tires

Hit a curb swerving to avoid getting hit. I'm paranoid about tires so feel free to tell my I'm being an idiot. I just got a new job with a huge pay cut and no paycheck for a few weeks so it's food or the tires but I'm definitely willing to eat the cost on a couple of tires if I need to. If I need new ones, does anyone know a rough estimate on how soon? Immediately? [image]

Comment: Hi Ashley and welcome to the site.  Please don't worry about looking like an "idiot": we are here to support people who feel like they're out of their depth because cars aren't their hobby / profession.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance, I'd say you're fine.  It looks like you hit the curb at a fairly shallow angle and abraded some of the rubber off the sidewall.  If there was real damage, I would expect to see more scraping on the edge of the wheel rim at the top of the picture.  Considering that you barely took the corner off one of the "f"s, I don't think this is a terminal issue.

My suggestion is that you watch that area for any bulging and keep an eye out for slow leaks.  If neither of those occur, you have a slightly less attractive tire (but didn't get hit!).

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely sleep better tonight :) I'll keep an eye on it for sure.

Comment: @Bob Cross, good answer, but you could consider moving that tyre to the rear as well.